# Android Studio not working on 64 Bit Windows 8.1

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to run Android studio on my 64 bit windows 8.1 machine and its not working. I went through earlier posts and have added JAVA_HOME and path in environment variables. I have JDK 7 installed and when I try to run studio64, it just shows an android image and after that nothing happens and it stays there. I could see that there were two android processes running in the background. Can any of you help ? TIA

Answer (score 0):

Is this first run ? if yes then wait it will run and then download SDK and all other thing in my case to had to wait 45mins

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79013/discussion-on-answer-by-user4847410-android-studio-not-working-on-64-bit-windows).